# Can't update securely and is therefore disabled?

Tags: 19.04

I have been all over this thread and nothing I've read or tried fixes this for me. I had wine installed but I removed it because I didn't want to mess with it. It appears that has compromised things for me. When I do `sudo apt update` I receive:

```
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository disco InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease               
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease [6,255 B]       
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease             
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Get:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages [42.1 kB]
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease      
Get:13 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages [39.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I *used* to be well versed in Linux but that was like 10 years ago and now I have no idea what I'm doing. Can someone please explain to me how to fix this like I was 5? I changed my server to main server.

I removed wine from the Other Software and it said to reload software so I did and it failed saying: `E:The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file.` When searching sources, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7ge.png). I'm running a backup now, as suggested in another thread, can someone help me on where to go from here? Thank you so much!!

UPDATE : content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
```

UPDATE #2: After running command provided by Jim

```
leslie@leslie-Lenovo-YOGA-720-13IKB:~$ sudo sed -i '60s/.*/# &/' /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for leslie: 
leslie@leslie-Lenovo-YOGA-720-13IKB:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository disco InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [72.1 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,740 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,269 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,164 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17.8 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,480 B]
Fetched 399 kB in 2s (232 kB/s)                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://your.repo.domain/repository/dists/disco/InRelease  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `artful` refers to 17.10 which has been EOL for a long time.  When a release goes EOL it's repos are moved from archives0 to old-releases, but you shouldn't have that repo on 19.04 so your sources.list are badly changed.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your post and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. As @guiverc commented, there are apparently some highly questionable entries therein.

Comment: @guiverc Oh no! I will update my post now. I never had Ubuntu 17 so I'm not sure how that would get on there? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Updated :)

Comment: Please do `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and copy all content to your post, as you're only copying portion of the content now.

Comment: seems like a partial list. You should be able to type `cat [filename]` and get the whole thing.

Comment: @Jim Updated :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Updated with the sources document, that appeared to have more information. Can you EITMLI5 what `cat [filename]` means?

Comment: `cat` is a terminal command that lists a file.

Comment: @OrganicMarble so the file name would be sources.list?

Comment: yes but type the whole thing /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @karel Similar, yes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `E: The repository no longer has a Release file`

Seems you have `artful` (Ubuntu 17.10) repository on your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, as it has reached EOL (End Of Life)— the repository therefore is no longer available.

To fix this, you need to delete or comment the repository, either way will do the jobs.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` using superuser privilege.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find for this line.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
```

Comment/delete it, if you comment it the line would look like this.

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
```

Adding `#` hashtag sign to beginning of the line, this will deactivate the `artful` repository.

#### `Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'`

Apparently OP has some unknown source on the package source list, `apt` doesn't recognized it hence the error above.

Same as before procedure, unrecognized source needs to be removed.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your-repo-name.list
```

Where `your-repo-name.list` is the problematic standalone source list.

---

Try `sudo apt update` again, it shouldn't produce any error now.

Comment: When I try to do this I get `** (org.gnome.gedit:24487): WARNING **: 22:27:33.756: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported` 
You were right though, the # was on everything else in that section except that one.

Comment: @LeslieLemon Try this then `sudo sed -i '60s/.*/# &/' /etc/apt/sources.list` followed by `sudo apt update`. This will add `#` character on specified line (60), where line 60 is your `artful` repo.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my post to include the results from that, from what I can tell it's fixed?

Comment: Where does `your.repo.domain` came from ? I forgot about that apparently

Comment: Uhh that is an excellent question I don't know the answer to... how can I find that out? When checking for software updates I'm being told failed to download repo info

Comment: Yup, you lost me.  I'm sorry, Linux has changed a lot since I last used it! That or I'm just getting old.

Comment: Have you find the file ?

Comment: No I haven't even the slightest clue what to look for, haha. What is the file I'm looking for?

Comment: Run this command on terminal `sudo find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec grep -i 'your.repo.domain' {} \; -print`.

Comment: `deb http://your.repo.domain/repository/ disco universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/your-repo-name.list` 
I'm so sorry I misunderstood!

Comment: Ok it seems we found the culprit of the error, run this `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your-repo-name.list` followed by `sudo apt update`

Comment: Hooray! That says all packages are up to date and no errors. I was also able to check for updates without errors! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @LeslieLemon If you find it helpful, consider accept this answer by clicking grey checkmark to turn into green checkmark ✅.

Comment: Done :) I really appreciate it! You made that very easy for someone like me haha

Comment: @LeslieLemon No problem, feel free to ask here anytime.